# TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, redux, bootstrap-modal

I need to fill the class with a modal dynamically. I have a quote dashboard with an action to view this quote in a request. When clicking I send the id of the quote to the store. My page then retrieves the full quote and displays the modal. Only I have an error when clicking and I cannot find a solution to my problem. I have the impression that the react does not take into account the fact that the class of change after the click.

**Dashbord**
[image: dashboard]

**Row btn "show"**

```js
                    <button type="button"
                            data-bs-toggle={"modal"}
                            data-bs-target={"#modal-pdf-" + estimate.estimate_name.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-').replaceAll('°', '-')}
                            onClick={() => dispatch(sendEstimateToShow(estimate.id))}
                            className="btn btn-primary">
                        <i className="bi bi-eye-fill"></i>
                    </button>
```

**Modal in dashboard page**

```js
    const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState("")


    const estimateToShow = useSelector(state => state.estimatesReducer.estimateToShow)

    const estimateToShowData = estimates.filter(estimate => estimate.id === estimateToShow)




!isEmpty(estimateToShowData) && (
                    <div className="modal"
                         id={modalTitle}
                         tabIndex="-1"
                         aria-hidden="true">
                        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
                            <div className="modal-content">
                                <div className="modal-header">
                                    <h5 className="modal-title"
                                        id="exampleModalLabel">{estimateToShowData[0].estimate_name}</h5>
                                    <button type="button" className="btn-close"
                                            onClick={() => setLoadPdf(false)}
                                            data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                                            aria-label="Close"></button>
                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-body d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
                                    {
                                        /*l'affichage du pdf est-il demandé ?*/
                                        loadPdf && (
                                            <PDFViewer height={"500px"}>
                                                <EstimateTemplatePdf currentEstimate={estimateToShowData[0]}/>
                                            </PDFViewer>
                                        )
                                    }

                                </div>
                                <div className="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button"
                                            onClick={() => setLoadPdf(false)}
                                            className="btn btn-secondary"
                                            data-bs-dismiss="modal">Fermer
                                    </button>
                                    <a
                                        href={instance.url}
                                        className={"btn btn-primary"}
                                        download="devis.pdf">
                                        Télécharger le devis
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**error message when I click on the eye**
[image: error-msg]

Comment: I don't see the issue in your code, but I'd be interested what modal you're using. Is the modal not a React component and trying to manipulate the DOM outside of React?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I use the classic bootstrap 5 modals, I have used them in other pages without problem.

Comment: Well, what I'm assuming is happening is you have both the native bootstrap JS and React both wanting to control the DOM, and conflict ensues. My recommendation would be to look for a React-based modal library (`react-modal` is pretty good)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will watch this